# Integrating Castle Windsor in ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApi

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

In WebApi 0.5.0, I would just define a new WebApiConfiguration, and register the CreateInstance method - this appears to have gone away in WebApi 4 (the current version that comes with ASP.net MVC 4).

How do I integrate Castle Windsor (or any other IoC container) with this new version of the framework?

Thanks

Comment: WebApi 6 is no longer supported.

Comment: @marcind - My apologies, got my version numbers wrong - updated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613137/114029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need can be found by starting from [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/20/RobustDIWithTheASPNETWebAPI.aspx).

If you follow the links in the post you will find all the information you need, including everything you need to register the components in the container.