# telerik html5 report viewer using ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, telerik-reporting

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/general-discussions/telerik-q3-2013-html5-report-viewer-using-ninject.aspx

does anyone have a solution for this. I have a library of repositories I want to make use of to generate data for a report. However the repostories are being used through injection and have a bunch of business logic tied into properties like user profiles etc set on the dbcontext. I want to be able to reuse this. I was able to use the report resolver to generate the report for me using ninject. but somewhere in the preprocessing it overrides this and creates its on instance of the report which of course does not have the ninject bindings on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, but one reason your Ninject bindings don't work is that `ReportsControllerBase` is **not** derived from `IController`; it's a WebAPI controller, so it implements `IHttpController`, which isn't getting picked up by your container.

This answer has a link to a sample project that helped me get around the different resolvers needed to get `ApiController`s to inject properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613137/534109